# how to fix this error XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

Tags: php, mysql, xml, wordpress, error-handling

i am using PHP & MYSQL on WordPress where i ma trying to add a Google map to my site with markers that are stored in MYSQL database.

i am trying to retrieve the selected data using **$wpdb class**  and using **DOM** .

but the system display this error:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?page_id=105&preview=true
Line Number 13, Column 15:      if ( query && query.indexOf( 'preview=true' ) !== -1 ) {
----------------------------^
```

where is the error in my code ?
i did not understand how to fix this XML error.

## code:

```
<?php
        /*
        Template Name: MAP2
        */

        get_header();
  ?>
<?php
global $wpdb;
// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");  
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);



// Search the rows in the site_coordinates table
$query = $wpdb->get_results("select * from site_coordinates");


header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
foreach ($query as $result){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("site id", $row['siteID']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['latitude']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['longitude']);

}

echo $dom->saveXML();



?>



<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: In anyway, can you able to see the XML structure you created here? can you print it? and show here

Comment: @Rupal no i am not able to see the created XML when i try to run the code it display the described error

Comment: try $dom->loadXML('<root><node/></root>'); just before echo $dom->saveXML(); and let us know here what happend

Comment: i added this line but still the same error

Comment: now  the error is changed `XML Parsing Error: undefined entity
Location: http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/index.php/locations3/
Line Number 13, Column 1:<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Lebanon Sites &raquo; Feed" href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/index.php/feed/" />
^`

Comment: You have foreach like "foreach ($query as $result){" but internally you used variable $row in data get, where $row will comes from? try to echo $row['siteID'] and other variable inside foreach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136928/discussion-between-rupal-and-nabil-jaroush).

Answer (score 0):

You can never have spaces in the attribute's name, that's why you are getting the error.

At this line:

```
$newnode->setAttribute("site id", $row['siteID']);
```

change it like this:

```
$newnode->setAttribute("site_id", $row['siteID']);
```

Or:

```
$newnode->setAttribute("siteId", $row['siteID']);
```

Comment: You are iterating over query as **result** but you are using $row to put in the values to the attributes.@NabilJaroush

Comment: @NabilJaroush can you please show me your result from the query?

Comment: i replaced the $ row by $result  but still the same error

Comment: @NabilJaroush please check the result array otherwise everything is working, i checked. you can see the result at : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/733b84ea41d3668ec49765d17a6648b6166cf28c

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code can be:

```
<?php
        /*
        Template Name: MAP2
        */

        get_header();
  ?>
<?php
global $wpdb;
// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");  
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);



// Search the rows in the site_coordinates table
$query = $wpdb->get_results("select * from site_coordinates");


header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
foreach ($query as $result){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("site id", $result['siteID']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $result['latitude']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $result['longitude']);

}

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```